Bluebeam Revu 21 scripting: invoke external program and create markup based on output
I've been looking to automate markup creation in Revu 21 Complete based on an external program's output, program that should be called by the script itself. The reason why I'm looking at Revu scripting for this is because the overall functionality should be accessible from a Revu Toolbar with a button click.
I have managed to create a script that does some processing to the active document (flattening/printing out) and I would then like the script to invoke an external program (e.g. a bat file, or a python file) to do further processing.
The script should wait for completion of the external program and then perform some more actions, mainly create some markups via the MarkupPaste command, creating markups via some XML output from the external program.
For example:
// Some initial preprocessing
BalancePages("-100", "last", "last", 0)
Flatten( true, 1, "-1", "")
PrintToFile("C:/test/testfile.pdf", "Default Printer", "Default Page Size", false, "", 1, 1, 1, false, 1))

// Invoke external program passing "C:/test/testfile.pdf" as an argument
// Wait for program completion
// External program will return: 
// 1) An XML string "myXmlString"
// 2) A page number "myPageNumber"
// 3) Two pX pY coordinates
[Some command to invoke the external program, wait for completion and get the results]

// Create markups based on result
MarkupPaste(myXmlString, myPageNumber, pX, pY)


Does anybody know if this is possible, and how?
I've contacted Bluebeam tech support, but they haven't been helpful so far (they said it's possible, but they didn't say how, nor they gave me confidence that they actually understood the requirements).
